# edit wordpress website automatically from a program

Tags: updates

i have recently made a program that checks prices on items on the internet and then saves it in a txt file.
My goal is to automatically check the prices every hour and then update my wordpress website with the information.

I have looked for an hour and i can't find a way to automatically update my website to show the right price.

The only way i have found is to install the application passwords plugin but i really don't want to use 40$ a month to make my website.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: WP already comes with support for application passwords with the REST API out of the box, there's a section in your users edit screen titled "Application Passwords" that can be used for authentication, and documentation in the official WP docs on how to use it at wordpress.org and developer.wordpress.org

Comment: Looking at the comments on [your other question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/415878/application-password-is-missing): Is this for a site on WordPress.com? If so, you'll need to contact their support team about this.